# Find Next Previous records with sorting

Tags: mysql

I'd like to make navigation links of search result, but not sure how to get previous and next IDs in MySQL?

Let's say, a user was searching stuff and ordered it by year, and the result set was like:

```
ID   YEAR
444  2013
333  2013
555  2013  <---- user clicks here (i.e. known ID is 555)
777  2012
111  2012
```

How do I get previous and next IDs (333, 777)?

Comment: depends on how you build your database, is it a relational database?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer**

You can try query like this, If it can help you.

```
select ID from tablename where phones like '99091505' AND ID = 555 order by year  
union all  
(select ID from tablename where phones like '99091505' AND ID < 555 order by year desc limit 1) 
union all  
(select ID from tablename where phones like '99091505' AND ID > 555 order by year asc limit 1)
```

**Old Answer**

This is not specific solution but general idea to achieve what you want!

At first, You should save the total number of rows found somewhere for a specific search.

so when user first time shown the search result, you will obviously show him first link, and keep track that the next will be 2nd link.

So user clicks next button, create your query to get `select xvy from tablename where abc=def order by year limit 1,1`

So if user is on 5th search result page and clicks on next button, your query will be like

```
select ID from tablename where abc=def order by year limit 5,1;
```

I think it will be better to do this by your programming language, not by mysql query.

Comment: Thanks, but I want a little bit different. A user searches for let's say phones and orders them by year.. And gets a page with 10 phones. Then, he clicks a page with a particular phone (id 555). But I'd like to show him links to a next phone (id 777) and previous (id 333). It's not a pager.

Comment: your updated answer returns me " Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY"

Comment: could you please, look at this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e482/6

I'd expect 111 and 444 IDs for previous and next

Comment: Sorry for replying late, @oddtwelve will this work? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e482/9/0